# How to bind with an external Web Server in Android

Tags: android

I don't know whether the title is appropriate or not. But here is my problem that I am trying to solve.

1. There is a Web Server (e.g. Apache) installed in my Android device.
2. There is another Android application developed by me that will send an image (taken from device camera) when it gets HTTP request.

For example, HTTP request can be as below:
http://192.168.16.56:8080/camera/snapshot?width=450&height=320

When HTTP request comes, Android will take the image from camera, resize it and provide it to the client.

I can solve this issue by creating a ServerSocket in Android. But I want to use the external Web-Server (e.g. Apache).

I heavily searched in internet but didn't find any clue using external Web-Server.

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Please share the code you have tried.

Comment: I tried using below GitHub project:
https://github.com/arktronic/cameraserve

Comment: Also tried with below: 

http://android-er.blogspot.jp/2014/02/android-sercerclient-example-client.html